# react router gives a url with a pad sign and a get parameter

Tags: reactjs, router

I am not sure how to get clean url with react router.

For the moment I have this:

```
http://localhost:8889/#/myRoute?_k=qq67x0
```

I would like to have this:

```
http://localhost:8889/myRoute
```

Is there a particular configuration step that I should set to fix this?

This is how I initialize the router:

```
import { browserHistory, Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute } from 'react-router
```

And here is my render function:

```
render((
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={MyComponent2} />
    <Route path="myComponent1" component={MyComponent1} />
    <Route path="myComponent2" component={MyComponent2} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

), document.getElementById('react-container'))

EDIT:

I have installed the last version of the router and now it works as expected.

Thanks!

Comment: One more thing: what version of React Router are you using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [the documentation under "What is that `?_k=ckuvup` junk in the URL?"](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#what-is-that-_kckuvup-junk-in-the-url):

> When a history transitions around your app with `push` or `replace`, it can store "location state" that doesn't show up in the URL on the new location, think of it a little bit like post data in an HTML form.
>
> The DOM API that hash history uses to transition around is simply `window.location.hash = newHash`, with no place to store location state. But, we want all histories to be able to use location state, so we shim it by creating a unique key for each location and then store that state in session storage. When the visitor clicks "back" and "forward" we now have a mechanism to restore the location state.

[The history package docs](https://github.com/rackt/history/blob/master/docs/HashHistoryCaveats.md) explain how to opt out, *if* you want to continue to use the hash history:

> If you prefer to use a different query parameter, or to opt-out of this behavior entirely, use the `queryKey` configuration option.
>
> ```js
> import createHistory from 'history/lib/createHashHistory'
>
> // Use _key instead of _k.
> let history = createHistory({
>   queryKey: '_key'
> })
>
> // Opt-out of persistent state, not recommended.
> let history = createHistory({
>   queryKey: false
> })
> ```

If you want to use the HTML 5 `pushState` API, as you mentioned in your question, then you should use `browserHistory` in your Router configuration instead of `hashHistory`:

```js
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

<Router history={browserHistory}>
  ...
```

She the [full "Histories" page in the React Router docs](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md) for more information.

Comment: I already use browserHistory like the nested animation example. I tried queryKey: false and it works as expected. I am still looking for a way to get rid of the hash sign.

Comment: If your URLs have the hashes in them, then you're using hashHistory :) Maybe sharing the router initialization code will help shed some light